# How to get current App Locale inside initState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to fetch data in initState method with provider based on current app Locale.

this is my code:

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    context.read<ApiProvider>().getHomeData(myLocale.languageCode);
  }
```

that result in this error:

> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_LocalizationsScope>() or
>   dependOnInheritedElement() was called before
>   _HomePageState.initState() completed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you cannot access `current App Locale` during initState (more concrete: before it completed).

The reason, so I believe, is that `Locale` tries to look up an InheritedWidget ancestor up in the tree, but the tree is just now being built (your widget is created during the parent widget's build)

- Try not to do the operation, when the widget is being built. Keep a check
- Have a variable which checks when the widget is built, and then you can call that

```
class _HomePageState extends State<Test> {

  bool isInitialized = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _initializeLocale(BuildContext context){
     Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
     context.read<ApiProvider>().getHomeData(myLocale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Setting the initialize to true, when widget is built
    // to perform our operation
    setState(() {
      isInitialized = true;

      // calling our method when it is ready and initialized
      _initializeLocale(context);
    });
   return Scaffold();
  }

}
```

Or you can simply call your method inside this `Widget build()`, cos all the method works, after the Widget is being built here only

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // simply call your method here, no initialize variable required
  _initializeLocale(context);
  return Scaffold();
}
```

Hope that helps. Keep learning :)